# Disable adding of new post (custom post type)

Tags: custom-post-types

How do I disable adding of new posts of a particular custom post type?

Found this code in Log Deprecated Notices plugin:

```
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( self::pt == $screen->id && ( $screen->action == 'add' || $_GET['action'] == 'edit' ) )
        wp_die( __( 'Invalid post type.', 'log-deprecated' ) );
    if ( self::pt != $screen->post_type )
        return;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16675677/247223), the "correct way" is:

```
register_post_type( 'custom_post_type_name', array(
  'capability_type' => 'post',
  'capabilities' => array(
    'create_posts' => false, // Removes support for the "Add New" function ( use 'do_not_allow' instead of false for multisite set ups )
  ),
  'map_meta_cap' => true, // Set to `false`, if users are not allowed to edit/delete existing posts
));
```

--

```
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'wpse_58290_disable_new_post' );
function wpse_58290_disable_new_post()
{
    if ( get_current_screen()->post_type == 'my_post_type' )
        wp_die( "You ain't allowed to do that!" );
}
```

Note that you'll also need to hide the UI elements, such as in the menu, and the "Add New" button in the `h2` tag on the edit screen.

Comment: Thanks, would you hide those just via CSS?

Comment: You might be better off removing the menu item by hooking onto `admin_menu` and searching for/unsetting the item in the global `$submenu`. As for the other items, check out the source & see if there's any suitable hooks/filters, otherwise fallback to CSS/JS.

Comment: Also how can I remove the Edit and Quick edit links

Comment: I don't have a menu item as I am adding the cpt to the menu via add_submenu_page

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the above/accepted answer, you could use this function to hide the actual links to the pages you want to disable.

```
remove_submenu_page( 
    'edit.php?post_type=product',
    'post-new.php?post_type=product' 
);
```

Comment: Please explain **why** that could solve the problem.

Comment: It is part of the solution. the answer of TheDeadMedic make sure they won't be able to visit the add and edit page, this piece will the items from the admin menu. In this case, custom post type product