# Prevent trash/delete action on specific post types

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, plugin-development, users

Edit:

In a plugin I am developing, I need to store payments, IPN and transactions for customers in both frontend and backend. However I am concerned that the admin will use his actions power to delete the transactions or financial data from site which has bad implications.

#### Question

How can I prevent the admin from deleting payments/financial data in a way that ensures that I'm not trying to restrict admins too much, but also takes customer information and financial data as high priority. I'm not asking what's the better way for me to do it? But rather asking what's the better way for WordPress community (as administration, as a customer) as I am trying to avoid future complaints about the way implemented to do this action.

**What I currently have**

```
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct() {

    // Do not allow payments and transactions to be trashed
    add_action( 'wp_trash_post',                            array( $this, 'disable_trash' ) );
    add_action( 'before_delete_post',                       array( $this, 'disable_trash' ) );
}

/**
 * Disable trash
 */
public function disable_trash( $post_id ) {
    global $post_type;

    if ( in_array( $post_type, array( 'payment', 'transaction' ) ) ) {
        wp_die( __( 'You are not allowed to trash payments or transactions.', 'xxx' ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: better is a subjective thing and whatever is better for me will not be better for you. You will have to define "better" in order to be able to get meaningful answer. Personally, I don't like what you are trying to do at all, there is a difference between making absolutely sure that the user understands the implications of deleting such data and actually preventing him from doing that

Comment: ... but if you are going to do it you have to handle all the relevant GUI as well

Comment: So you are saying that it would be more user friendly to just warn users about the implications of erasing such data rather than preventing them ? Actually that makes sense

Comment: Don't know if it is more user friendly, but I just instinctively object to taking power from admins. admins should be able to admin their sites.

Comment: @MarkKaplun On the other hand, when it comes to financial data, it may be mandatory for auditing purposes to rule out tampering by admins. That might be better for the admins themselves as well.

Comment: @cjbj, as you also said, this do not prevent tampering, just makes it harder

Comment: I'm also not very comfortable with taking power from admins and preventing them from doing obvious administrative stuff. However, as cjbj pointed out this is highly sensitive financial data that includes IPN/payments which are related to the customers on site. So I have been thinking how to warn the user that this data should not be removed in any case UNLESS the customer is also aware of the implications. I'm trying to protect both the admins and customers from financial data loss.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's another approach using the `map_meta_cap` filter that's applied within the [`map_meta_cap()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/map_meta_cap/) function within the `has_cap()` method of the `WP_User` class (*PHP 5.4+*):

```
add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', function ( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args )
{
    // Nothing to do
    if( 'delete_post' !== $cap || empty( $args[0] ) )
        return $caps;

    // Target the payment and transaction post types
    if( in_array( get_post_type( $args[0] ), [ 'payment', 'transaction' ], true ) )
        $caps[] = 'do_not_allow';       

    return $caps;    
}, 10, 4 );
```

where we target the *delete_post* meta capability and the `payment` and `transaction` custom post types.

As far as I understand and skimming through the [`get_post_type_capabilities()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_capabilities/) function we don't need the `map_meta_cap` argument set as true, in the `register_post_type` settings, to target the `delete_post` meta capability.

*ps:*
*[Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/what-is-the-use-of-map-meta-cap-filter) are some good descriptions of the `map_meta_cap` filter and helpful examples by Justin Tadlock [here](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/10/meta-capabilities-for-custom-post-types) and Toscho [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53234/26350)*. *[Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/192366/make-certain-pages-uneditable-by-editors/192374#192374) I found an old  example that I had forgot I wrote, that we could also adjust to avoid trash/delete on some given pages and user roles.* *[Here's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/58292/26350) an answer by TheDeadMedic that links to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235257/wordpress-disable-add-new-on-custom-post-type/16675677#16675677) by Seamus Leahy regarding `register_post_type` approach. 
[Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=do_not_allow%20map_meta_cap) are some more examples on this site. Hope it helps!*

Comment: if( in_array( get_post_type( $args[0] ), [ 'payment', 'transaction' ], true ) missing a ) at end, other than that works like charm.

Comment: ps: The admins of your site might also upload a plugin or change the theme, that can modify the database to their likings. So you should consider that kind of power too and also disable theme/plugin editors. Check e.g. out the `DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT` and `DISALLOW_FILE_MODS` constants [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Disable_the_Plugin_and_Theme_Editor). @AhmedMahdi

Answer (score 5):

A better way to prevent deletion would be to disable that [capability](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) for all roles. When you [register your post types](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) 'payment' and 'transaction' also define a `capability_type` with the same name as your post type. This will give you capabilities `read_payment`, `edit_payment` and `delete_payment` (same for transaction).

You can then deny this capability on roles in this way:

```
$wp_roles->remove_cap( 'editor', 'delete_payment' );
$wp_roles->remove_cap( 'admin', 'delete_payment' );
```

Always beware that since admins can edit code on your site, they will still be able to circumvent the deletion, unless you block code editing in the backend and restrict ftp and database access. Also [read this discussion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1665/getting-a-list-of-currently-available-roles-on-a-wordpress-site) on getting all available roles.

Comment: Yes I am aware that an admin can just remove the entries from phpmyadmin. I'm only trying to do my best to ensure that the frontend/backend provides no way to delete that data.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code in a website , where we can hide edit, trash, view buttons even in bulk edit drop-down,

```
if(!current_user_can('administrator')) //not an admin
{
    add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions', 10, 1 );
    function remove_row_actions( $actions )
    {
        if( get_post_type() === 'post' ) {
            unset( $actions['edit'] );
            unset( $actions['view'] );
            unset( $actions['trash'] );
            unset( $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] );
        }
        return $actions;
    }
}

if(!current_user_can('administrator'))//not and admin
{
    global $pagenow;
    if ( 'post.php' == $pagenow || 'post-new.php' == $pagenow ) {
        add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpse_125800_custom_publish_box' );
        function wpse_125800_custom_publish_box() {
            $style = '';
            $style .= '<style type="text/css">';
            $style .= '#delete-action, .bulkactions';
            $style .= '{display: none; }';
            $style .= '</style>';

            echo $style;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you simply hide a button with css, the user can unhide it in his browser and do as he pleases.

Comment: Yes, for bulk action there is a possibility to unhide it and do the actions.

We can try this

[code]             $output = preg_replace('#<div class="bulkactions">(.*?)      </div>#', ' ', $incoming_data);
                        $output = preg_replace('#<div id="delete-action">(.*?)</div>#', ' ', $incoming_data); [/code]