# How to disable delete option for a specific page?

Tags: pages, wp-admin, hooks

i found many questions like this but nothing matching to my requirement.Here i need to lock a specific page named settings,not to be  deleted by other admins.But it should able to edit. Is there any way to lock a specific page.

Comment: Yes this is absolutely possible. Probably in a [way like so](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/240210). What have you tried? Where have the other solutions you found failed you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preventing the trash post action is a crude way of approaching it. You have to kill the application and display an ugly error message, and the UI for deleting the post will still be there.

Instead I suggest using the `map_meta_cap` filter. This will allow you to change a user's [capabilities](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/roles-and-capabilities/) for a single post.

Normally when WordPress checks if a user can delete a post it checks "can the user `delete_post` for this post?". The way it figures this out is with the `map_meta_cap` function.

This function decides which capabilities `delete_post` maps to. For example, if the user created the post then the function maps `delete_post` to `delete_posts`. So if the user has the `delete_posts` capability then they can delete the post. If the user did *not* create the post, then the function maps `delete_post` to `delete_others_posts`.

The `map_meta_cap` filter allows us change this mapping. So we'll use it to map `delete_post` to `do_not_allow` for this specific post. Then no users will be able to delete that post.

This is the function for doing this:

```
function wpse_312694_restrict_page_deletion( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ) {
    $post_id = $args[0];

    if ( $cap === 'delete_post' && $post_id === 117 ) {
        $caps[] = 'do_not_allow';
    }

    return $caps;
}
add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'wpse_312694_restrict_page_deletion', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Are you sure that the code is running well. After using this set of code the site crashed.

Comment: There was a typo on `filter`, it's fixed now.

Comment: its working now .....but its not editable .....i need it to be editable.

Comment: Sorry, I left out a bit: `$cap === 'delete_post'`, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

found the solution

```
function restrict_page_deletion($post_ID)
{
  $restricted_pageId = 177;

  if(($post_ID == $restricted_pageId))
   {
    echo "You are not authorized to delete this page.";
    exit;
   }
}
add_action('wp_trash_post', 'restrict_page_deletion', 10, 1);
```